# Symfony visitor counter

Tags: symfony, count, visitor-pattern

I was wondering if symfony provides a way to access all the connected users, in order to count them.
Otherwise, maybe there is a plugin/bundle to do that ?

I know this is possible with a time column on my User table, but I don't really like this solution.

All answer is welcome,

Thanks in advance !

Comment: are you interested in registered users only?

Comment: I forget to precise it, yes only registered users, anons doesn't interest me.

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony2's default Session implementation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) just wraps PHP's native session handling, which by default is backed by session files in the file system.

If you need more control over user sessions than that gives you, you could consider implementing your own (database-backed?) [session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php).

I'm not aware of any bundles that do this, but http://knpbundles.com/ is generally the place to go to for Symfony2 bundles.

:-)